# Representing a linear combination of matrices as some kind of inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra, products

If I have a linear combination of two numbers $\lambda_1y_1+\lambda_2y_2$, I can represent it as $\mathbf y \cdot\vec \lambda$, i.e., an inner product of two vectors.

If I have a linear combination of two vectors $\lambda_1\mathbf y_1+\lambda_2 \mathbf y_2$, I can represent it as matrix-vector product $\mathbf Y\vec \lambda$.

How can I do something similar for linear combination of two matrices $\lambda_1 Y_1+\lambda_2 Y_2$?

Comment: Nothing stops us in using a matrix $\pmatrix{Y_1\\Y_2}$ with *matrix entries*..

Comment: ... and if the definition of the linear function is independent of basis then $\pmatrix{Y_1\\Y_2}$ is a (1,2) tensor which maps the vector $\pmatrix{\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2}$ to the (1,1) tensor $\lambda_1Y_2 + \lambda_2Y_2$.

Answer (score 0):

In the language of Linear Algebra, the $y$'s are looked upon as vectors in some vector space, and what you do is writing those vectors' coordinate representation as columns of a matrix.

Hence this requires fixing a coordinate system (i.e. a basis) for the space first.

In your first example, the numbers can in fact be looked upon as vectors in the $1$-dimensional space, which is why each column's height in $\mathbf{y}$ is $1$.

In your third example, matrices (say $M_{n \times m}(\mathbb{R})$) can also be viewed as a $nm$-dimensional space, but writing linear combinations in a similar way requires writing each matrix as a column vector. For example,

$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    3 \\
    4 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ for 
$\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 2 \\
    3       & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.